# Is there any way to restrict app-only permission for Graph API in Azure AD to a certain group of people?

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

For an application to work, it requires read/write access to most user calendars in the organization, which is achieved with app-only permission requirement for Graph API, which allows access to all calendars.

This looks a little bit too wide for some security people, and they asked me if there is some way to restrict this to a specific subset of accounts. I haven't found any settings in this direction. "Grant permissions" in App registration section of the Azure AD management portal will give access to all user calendars, including the future ones too.
Could somebody give a straight answer if it is or not possible; and I would be grateful for a link to an official Microsoft page where that can be seen.
Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, well the app-only permission basically gives the app a role in the Graph API which allows it to read all calendars and you can't limit that. Another option might be to use delegated permissions. In that case the users using the app themselves would need access to the calendars the app reads/updates.

Comment: Yes, this is what I could tell them too. Delegated permission won't be a feasible option with that amount of users, and for that usage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. follow the steps below and wait 30 to an hour for policy to propagate.

Configure ApplicationAccessPolicy

To configure an application access policy and limit the scope of application permissions:

1. Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell. For details, see Connect to
   Exchange Online PowerShell.
2. Identify the app’s client ID and a mail-enabled security group to restrict the app’s access to.
   o   Identify the app’s application (client) ID in the Azure app registration portal.
   o   Create a new mail-enabled security group or use an existing one and identify the email address for the group.
3. Create an application access policy.
   Run the following command, replacing the AppId, PolicyScopeGroupId, and Description arguments.
   `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AppId e7e4dbfc-046f-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@contoso.com -AccessRight RestrictAccess -Description "Restrict this app to members of distribution group EvenUsers."`
4. Test the newly created application access policy.
   Run the following command, replacing the AppId and Identity arguments.
   `Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity user1@contoso.com -AppId e7e4dbfc-046-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b`
   The output of this command will indicate whether the app has access to User1’s mailbox

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendars-permissions
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0